# How do you place "<%" inside a jsp?

Tags: jsp

I am trying to escape the special characters of a jsp.  Specifically, I want the <% to appear on the page without starting a scriptlet.  How do I do that?

Note:  I don't want <% to be on the page, I want to print <% inside a string of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string up and let the Javascript concatenate it client-side:

```
tag = "<" + "%";
document.write(tag);
```